# non template class using a template class as member variable

Tags: c++, templates

hi i am stuck tryng to use a class declaring as template class, thus my knowledge of templates is basic.

```
//this is my code
#include "templateClassImp.cpp"
clase aClass{
public:
aClass();//implementing in cpp file
private:
ATemplateClass<class EMode, char> mMenberVariable;/*<< Doenst like this!!!! error compiling*/
}
```

//--------------------------

//templateClassImp.cpp

```
template<class Emode, class element = char>
class templateClassImp{}
```

//what i want to achieve is to use that class inside my non template class.

Comment: I think it's time to buy a book and see the syntax for template classes are instantiated.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. A class that is not a template has the types of all its members fixed in the definition. Do you want your non-template class to hold a particular *instantiation* of a template? (Side note: including a .cpp is usually a bad idea)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to either make `aClass` a class template, or provide template parameters for `mMenberVariable`.

```
template <class T1, class T2=char>
class aClass
{
public:
  aClass();
private:
  ATemplateClass<T1, T2> mMenberVariable;
};
```

or

```
class aClass
{
public:
  aClass();
private:
  ATemplateClass<int, double> mMenberVariable;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to parameterize all template parameters in a template definition to use it.

```
ATemplateClass<EMode, char> mMenberVariable
```